# "What was a little X going to do?" or "what was a little of X going to do?"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

What the correct option? Or maybe the *of* is optional? Example:

> What was a little more (of) smoke going to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the thing that is going to help is a single noun, with or without an adjective, then you don't need *of* e.g. a little love, a little cold water, a little help etc.

But if it is more complicated than that you will need *of* e.g. *a little of his love*, *a little of that water*, *a little of my mother's help,* etc.